# Setup Slurm partition for only interactive jobs

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

is there a way to setup on SLURM a partition to not accept interactive jobs? and in the opposite way a partition that accept only interactive jobs?

The main partition setup I use is like:

> ```
> NodeName=worker CPUs=xxx Boards=xxx SocketsPerBoard=xxx CoresPerSocket=xxx ThreadsPerCore=xxx RealMemory=xxx Weight=xxx
> ```

Thanks